# Variable is printed properly right before an if else loop, but does not retain that value one in the if else loop

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

I've written a program that reads an account value from a text file and then assigns these values to a variable for each account. Once this is done, reading from the same text file, an action to be done to each account value is identified in the format "Account# Actiontype ActionModifier". All the correct values are being scanned and the proper values are being stored when I insert printfs to check, but immediately after the correct value is printed, the value is put through an else if loop. When doing this for some reason the value is being read as 1 no matter what and is executing the actions in the else if loop as if it were equal to 1.

```
loopState = 1;
while(loopState != 0)

{

for(i = 1;i < 100 ;i++)
    {

    if(i < 6)// This executes fine
    {
        fscanf(bankfile,"%f",&accValue);
    switch(i)
        {
            case 1:
                acc1 = accValue;
                break;
            case 2:
                acc2 = accValue;
                break;
            case 3:
                acc3 = accValue;
                break;
            case 4:
                acc4 = accValue;
                break;
            case 5:
                acc5 = accValue;
                printf("Done module one\n");
                break;

        }
    }
    else // scan for the the first value, than the second, then the third
    {
            fscanf(bankfile,"%d",&accNum);

            if(accNum != 0)
            {
                fscanf(bankfile,"%c",&accAction);

                if(accAction == 'W' || accAction == 'D')
                {
                    fscanf(bankfile,"%f",&actValue);
                    printf("%d %c %.2f\n",accNum,accAction,actValue);//this will be correct
                    printf("%d\n",accNum); //this will print say "2"

                    if(accNum = 1)//but this if statement will be run
                    {//thus printing the below printf
                        printf("If accNum = 1 this will print\n");
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'W':
                                final1 = withdrawl(acc1,actValue);
                                break;
                            case 'D':
                                final1 = deposit(acc1,actValue);
                                break;
                         }
                     }

                     else if(accNum = 2)
                     {
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'W':
                                final2 = withdrawl(acc2,actValue);
                                break;
                            case 'D':
                                final2 = deposit(acc2,actValue);
                                break;
                         }
                     }
                     else if(accNum = 3)
                     {
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'W':
                                final3 = withdrawl(acc3,actValue);
                                break;
                            case 'D':
                                final3 = deposit(acc3,actValue);
                                break;
                         }
                     }
                     else if(accNum = 4)
                     {
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'W':
                                final4 = withdrawl(acc4,actValue);
                                break;
                            case 'D':
                                final4 = deposit(acc4,actValue);
                                break;
                         }
                     }
                     else if(accNum = 5)
                     {
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'W':
                                final5 = withdrawl(acc5,actValue);
                                break;
                            case 'D':
                                final5 = deposit(acc5,actValue);
                                break;
                         }
                     }
                }
                else if(accAction == 'B' || accAction == 'U')
                {   
                printf("%d %c\n",accNum,accAction);//this will be correct
                printf("%d\n",accNum);//this will print say "4"
                    if(accNum = 1)//but this if statement will be run
                    {//thus printing this printf below
                        printf("If accNum = 1 this will print\n");
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'B':
                                final1 = balance(acc1);
                                break;
                            case 'U':
                                final1 = update(acc1);
                                break;
                         }
                     }

                     else if(accNum = 2)
                     {
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'B':
                                final2 = balance(acc2);
                                break;
                            case 'U':
                                final2 = update(acc2);
                                break;
                         }
                     }
                     else if(accNum = 3)
                     {
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'B':
                                final3 = balance(acc3);
                                break;
                            case 'U':
                                final3 = update(acc3);
                                break;
                         }
                     }
                     else if(accNum = 4)
                     {
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'B':
                                final4 = balance(acc4);
                                break;
                            case 'U':
                                final4 = update(acc4);
                                break;
                         }
                     }
                     else if(accNum = 5)
                     {
                        switch(accAction)
                        {
                            case 'B':
                                final5 = withdrawl(acc5,actValue);
                                break;
                            case 'U':
                                final5 = deposit(acc5,actValue);
                                break;
                         }
                     }

                }
            }
            else
            loopState = 0;
    }
}
 }
    printf("Exited Loop");
}
```

From my understanding I can't see where the value is being altered if just the line before it is being seen as the correct value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional statements are doing assignment.

```
else if (accNum = 3)
```

should be

```
else if (accNum == 3)
```